# How to debug npm modules?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

Normally you `yarn/npm install react`, then use it with `import React from 'react'`

Say you want to debug a React source and you clone a GitHub repo.

How do you use the source in your project instead of the lib version?

- edit

To further develop philipheinser's answer, here's what I encountered with doing `npm link draft-js-mention-plugin`

`npm link` seems to run `npm run build` which is the `scripts` command in the `package.json` that you want to link.

with `draft-js-mention-plugin`, npm run build runs `../node_modules/.bin/rimraf lib` and I had to go up a directory and run `npm install` to install the `rimraf`

`draft-js-mention-plugin` has parent `draft-js-plugins` and it has its own package.json

Answer (score 4):

You can use `npm link` your version of the code: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link.html

Comment: I'm still trying to do thi, does npm link `build` your source and link it? I want to debug with raw source version of the code .. does `npm link` help me to do that?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/how-to-contribute.html#development-workflow maybe this helps you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mimic a more production like situation you might use this workflow:

Create a package of your submodule locally:

```
cd /path/to/your/module
npm pack
```

*This will create a .tgz file of your package in /path/to/your/module*

Install the local package of the submodule in your application:

```
cd /path/to/your/application    
npm install /path/to/your/module/<YourModule>-<YourModulesVersion>.tgz
```

*This will install the .tgz file in your application's node_modules directory*

**These steps should be repeated after adjustments to your module.**